# Has JavaScript typeof ever returned "array"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen this idiom show up in various open-source projects:

```
it instanceof Array || typeof it == "array"
```

I know the second half cannot be true in ECMAScript 5 (or 6), but is/was there ever an implementation that would return "array" from typeof?  Or is this a case of bogus defensive programming?

Comment: Did you seriously see this in actual code? Please show a link…

Comment: I would say ignorance rather than defensive. Ignorance is not an offense just not known something, developers that wrote that does not known that does not makes sense.

Comment: I think there used to be more cases in 'dojo' but I only see one remaining: [_firebug/firebug.js:1036](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/d7a7e0c997b847debabfc59476c2a4cb0c23d1aa/_firebug/firebug.js#L1036)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, at least since the first version of ECMAScript.

[**ECMAScript 1**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) (June 1997)

> **11.4.3 - The `typeof` operator**
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `typeof` *UnaryExpression* is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. If Type(Result(1)) is Reference and GetBase(Result(1)) is **null**, return `"undefined"`.
> 3. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
> 4. Return a string determined by Type(Result(3)) according to the following table:
>
>    - Undefined: `"undefined"`
>    - Null: `"object"`
>    - Boolean: `"boolean"`
>    - Number: `"number"`
>    - String: `"string"`
>    - Object (native and doesn’t implement [[Call]]): `"object"`
>    - Object (native and implements [[Call]]): `"function"`
>    - Object (host): Implementation-dependent

[**ECMAScript 2**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%202nd%20edition,%20August%201998.pdf) (August 1998)

No changes.

[**ECMAScript 3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (December 1999)

No relevant changes.

> **11.4.3 - The `typeof` operator**
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `typeof` *UnaryExpression* is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. If Type(Result(1)) is not Reference, go to step 4.
> 3. If GetBase(Result(1)) is **null**, return `"undefined"`.
> 4. Call GetValue(Result(1)).
> 5. Return a string determined by Type(Result(4)) according to the following table:
>
>    - Undefined: `"undefined"`
>    - Null: `"object"`
>    - Boolean: `"boolean"`
>    - Number: `"number"`
>    - String: `"string"`
>    - Object (native and doesn’t implement [[Call]]): `"object"`
>    - Object (native and implements [[Call]]): `"function"`
>    - Object (host): Implementation-dependent

**ECMAScript 4**

This spec was abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completion, those are often-used methods to check for arrays:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr instanceof Array
arr.constructor === Array
```

Or in case you wish to check an object-property:

```
var obj = {
    name: "myObject",
    list: [

    ]
};
```