# Variable by id and class type

Tags: javascript, object

How to know the type of variable containing the result of document.getElementById()?

For example, on using alert(typeof variable), I get object but we refer these variables like array in document.getElementsByClassName[i].

I want to know what exactly is the type of the variable containing the value and how are we using it as an array.

```
var cv = document.getElementById("xyz");
alert(typeof cv); //Alerts object
```

But we use these variables as arrays like..

```
var cv = document.getElementsByClassName("xyz");
cv[0].style.height="200px";    //use as array
```

On evaluating it further using array.isarray(),it turns out that it is not an array..So how are we able to use the variable as an array like in the code written "use as array"?

Comment: A good hint when you see a function name is to look the singular or plural form: in getElementById, element is in singular, so you've directly the element ; but in getElementsByClassName, elements is in plural, so you've a collection of elements.

Comment: Array.isArray(cv) should tell you if your object is an array

Comment: Any `array` is an `object` in Javascript, It means `typeof [] === "object"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has JavaScript typeof ever returned "array"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264923/has-javascript-typeof-ever-returned-array)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

`typeof` returns object for both arrays and objects, all it means is that it is a non-primitive data type.

If you are interested in determining if it is an array, you can use `Array.isArray()` like this

```
const values = [1,2,3]
if (Array.isArray(values))
  console.log("It's an array")
```

Notice that I used `console.log` instead of `alert()`, if you have many of them it doesn't hold up the execution.

Comment: Sir it turns out that it is not an array....How are we using it like an array then as in the code written "use as array"?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("xyz")` will give you an array, even if their is only one element, it is still an array

Comment: Sir on running against console.log(Array.isArray(xyz)) prints false on console log indicating that it is not an array..Is there something i am missing?

Comment: Strange, it appears that it is returning an object, with string values as keys, eg "0", "1", "2" etc. Coincidentally, javascript allows you to refer the the first element as either '[0]' or '["0"]'.

Answer (score 0):

- [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) gives you a reference to a single DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object
- [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) gives you an array-like object, which is a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements